# OpenMp example program

Tags: c++, openmp

I have to parallelize a program with OpenMP and I don't have any idea. The code below is a similar (very) semplified problem. I have a class whose attributes are a vector and its lenght. The method 'work' calculate each new element v[i] of the vector as the average value of the one before and the one after (considering periodic boundaries, ie element 0 is the average of element 1 and element (len-1)).

class:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

class A{

private:

    std::vector<int> v;
    int len;

public:

    A(): len(0), v(0){
        v[0] = 0;
    }

    A(unsigned n): len(n), v(n){
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            v[i] = 2*(i+1);
    }

    void work(){
        std::vector<int> temp(len);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            temp[i] = (v[((i-1+len)%len)] + v[((i+1)%len)]) / 2;
        v.swap(temp);
    }

    void out(){
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            std::cout << v[i] << "  ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    ~A(){}

};
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "omp.h"
#include "class.cpp"

int main () {

    A a(5);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        a.work();
    }

    a.out();

    return 0;
}
```

The method work is called multiple times. Can someone write me few lines of code to explain what to do?

Comment: Well, who is the splendid man that enjoys himself putting negative votes to my question? I need to solve this problem, I know that this is a professional site and probably my question are stupid (and very helpful for those people like me that are studing), but that splendid instead of preventing other questions from my account can teach me how to use OpenMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution, in the method work of the class you have to write before the cycle:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

that's all!!!

Comment: Hey Wellen, you're absolutely right!

Comment: Now only one question... if I have to print a matrix, is it correct to use a #pragma omp parallel for before the two cycles?